# Parsing constant and identifier

Tags: peg, pegjs

I want to match a constant, which is basically an all uppercase string.

Also, I want to match an identifier, which can contain a mix of lowercase and uppercase letters.

```
Start 
  = Constant
  / Identifier

Identifier
  = h:[A-Za-z_] t:[a-zA-Z0-9_]* { return { type: 'IDENTIFIER', value: h + t.join('') } }

Constant
  = h:[A-Z] t:[A-Z_0-9]* { return { type: 'CONSTANT', value: h + t.join('') } }
```

The problem is, when I try to match `Asd`, it says: `Line 1, column 2: Expected [A-Z_0-9] or end of input but "s" found.`

It seems it matches the Constant rule but doesn't swap to the Identifier one even when it fails...

The problem seems to be that a constant is also a valid identifier, but I can't figure out rules to break the ambiguity, I think if Constant match fails it should just try the Identifier rule...

Answer (score 1):

The problem here happens because parsing expressions grammars are not like context free grammars. They get the first match instead of backtracking. The `Constant` rule is defined before `Identifier`. `Asd` matches the start character for a constant rule, but the next char doesn't, therefore, it throws an error, because it is deterministic. Hopefully, it is easy to fix:

```
Start 
  = Constant
  / Identifier

Identifier
  = h:[A-Za-z_] t:[a-zA-Z0-9_]* { return { type: 'IDENTIFIER', value: h + t.join('') } }

Constant
  = h:[A-Z] ![a-z] t:[A-Z_0-9]* { return { type: 'CONSTANT', value: h + t.join('') } }
```

Outputs:

```
{
   "type": "IDENTIFIER",
   "value": "Asd"
}
```

PEGs are, by default, deterministic and avoid ambiguity, as your rule defines.